# Convert Array of Bitset to vector<bool>

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, bitset

I have set of zeroes and ones as my input like below, I need to do some pairwise Boolean operation (and, or, Xor, not) between them (consider each line as).

```
111100000000
101100000010
111011100000
111100000001
001100010001
```

The code for reading and storing each line is:

```
int lineCounter = 0;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    myinput[lineCounter] = bitset<LEN> (std::string(line));
    lineCounter++;
}
```

Right now I am using array of bitset to store each line `bitset<LEN> myinput[NUMBER];` that `LEN` is size of each line and `NUMBER` is number of lines in my input file. But the problem is I don't want to specify `LEN` and `NUMBER` during compile time since I have to work with different input. having said that I want user give the `LEN` and `NUMBER` as an input argument when running the program. Since I can not do dynamic allocation for bitset I want to use vector but don't know how should I use it to fulfill my job! 
can you please tell how can read and store my input and do pairwise boolean operation with help of vector or anything else that can handle dynamic allocation.

Comment: Boost `dynamic_bitset` ?  [The `dynamic_bitset` class is nearly identical to the `std::bitset` class. The difference is that the size of the `dynamic_bitset` (the number of bits) is specified at run-time during the construction of a `dynamic_bitset` object, whereas the size of a `std::bitset` is specified at compile-time through an integer template parameter.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)

Answer (score 3):

You  can read the input like this:

```
vector< vector<bool> > set;
int lineCounter = 0;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
         string input = string(line)
   vector<bool> line;
   while(input.size!=0){
        if(input.front()=='0'{
            line.pushBack(false);
        }
        else{
            line.pushBack(true);
        }
    input.erase(0,1);
    }
    set.pushback(line);
    lineCounter++;
}
```

As far as pairwise boolean operations, iterating over the two vectors and performing the appropriate bitwise opperation should suffice.

Comment: my question is how can I change it to vector<bool>, so your answer is not helpful

Comment: so you want to know how to rewrite your code with vector<bool> instead of bitset?

Comment: exactly, since it seems I need 2D vector<bool> in my case! correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Am1rr3zA totally changed the answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, regarding pairwise Boolean operation do we have better solution?

Comment: I found this question regarding that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048749/bitwise-operations-on-vectorbool

Comment: Beside you have too many compile error in your answers, 1- you can not use teh same name for your vector as you have for your reading file (line) 2- it's push_back not pushBack 3- there is no input.size 4- ...