# Applying or(||) operator on two vectors containing only 0 and 1

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++14

I have two vectors:
A = {1,0,1,1},
B = {0,1,1,1}.
How can I apply or operator on these two so that i could get a vector:
C = {0,0,1,1} .

Comment: You say you want to use OR, but your expected output suggests AND. Which is it? And what have you tried?

Comment: it sounds like you want an AND operator, not an OR operator... `1011` V `0111` = `1111` vs `1011` ^ `0111` = `0011`

Comment: Depending on your use case, [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) might be worth considering.

Comment: As the question is tagged `vector` it seems you are looking for a dynamic bitset. For this, `std::vector<int>` as well as `std::vector<bool>` (due to the peculiar nature of the latter) should be avoided. If a dynamic bitset is indeed what you are looking for, the Q&A I've linked to below might be an appropriate duplicate for this question. See also [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) and [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bitwise operations on vector<bool>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048749/bitwise-operations-on-vectorbool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop through them element-wise using indices

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> A = {1, 0, 1, 1};
    std::vector<int> B = {0, 1, 1, 1};

    std::vector<int> C(A.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i)
    {
        C[i] = A[i] && B[i];
    }

    for (auto value : C)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: If the arrays are fixed size, you can also consider using an `std::bitset`.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<int> C;
std::transform(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(),
    std::back_inserter(C), std::logical_and<int>());
```

Comment: Also need to check `B.size() >= A.size()`.   The behaviour is undefined if this isn't true.