# Convert and Store struct to binary in C++

Tags: c++, struct, binary

I want to **convert** a struct, which consists of various data types (long, char[x], char*), to binary and **store** it in a variable (I do not know the correct or optimal data type for this).

CONVERSION
For strings: I have converted every character to its ascii code and then converting the ascii code from decimal to binary.
For numbers: I have converted the number from decimal to binary.

STORAGE
I stored the output of the above conversions to char[], which consisted of '0' and '1'.

My question is, how to perform a conversion of a struct to binary and in what data type to store it. Ideally, i would like to store it in binary format, in order to perform various actions on it. (the char[] data type I used seems a little wrong, because it is string actually, not binary)

**EDIT:** I would prefer to avoid using libraries that are not included in standard C++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to serialize and deserialize a class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234724/is-it-possible-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-class-in-c)

Comment: You're mixing concepts. A struct _is_ a type (a user-defined type), while a variable _has_ a type. A variable definitely can have a struct type. Also, each character already _has_ a binary value. That's how computers work.

Comment: @Botje I would prefer not to use other libraries, but i will give it a try probably, thanks

Comment: @MSalters I know the concepts of structs and variables. My problem is not the type actually. Both structs (that consist of variables) and variables occupy a "place" in memory. So i would like to handle that "place of memory" (their binary values) somehow.

Answer (score 0):

> I stored the output of the above conversions to char[], which consisted of '0' and '1'.

Simply store the binary data as bytes instead (*eg* not `['1','1','1','1','0','1','1','1']` but `0xf7`). Store 8 bits per `char` for as many `char`s as you have data. If you're using c++17 use `std::byte` instead of `char`.

Answer (score 0):

May it would be better to use a vector of bool as your storge, e.g., convert each datatype as you told and then put their output in vector and then retrieve them in the order that they were placed in the container. Although, it's better to use a vector of std::byte.

Comment: do you know if i can perform bitwise operations in vectors?

Comment: There is a bunch of solutions and examples for bitwise operations in vectors. take a look in here as an instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048749/bitwise-operations-on-vectorbool