# Bitwise Operations on vector of vectors

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

### Problem Description

Hello, I'm re-writing an old program I made that solves [nonograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram).
As part of solving it, I generate (for some of the lines) an array of all possible ways to fit the numbers in.

I want to create a piece of code, that will merge all the possible placements.

Meaning, that for example, in pseudo code:

```
[[0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 1]]

OR - [1, 1, 1]
AND - [0, 0, 1]
```

The result of the two operations will let me know exactly where we have a fixed value.
`[?, ?, 1]`

### Assumptions

- The solution is desired in C++.
- The placements are stored in a `vector<vector<bool>>`.
- The size of all the inner `vector`s is the same.
- It doesn't matter which bitwise operation is done, just that it can be applied to all the vectors.

### Possible Solution

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<vector<bool>> options =
            {{false, false, true},
             {true,  false, true},
             {false, true,  true}};

    vector<bool> merge_and, merge_or;
    bool flag;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < options[0].size(); j++) cout << options[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < options[0].size(); i++) {
        flag = options[0][i];
        for (j = 1; j < options.size(); j++) {
            flag = flag & options[j][i];
        }
        merge_and.push_back(flag);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < options[0].size(); i++) {
        flag = options[0][i];
        for (j = 1; j < options.size(); j++) {
            flag = flag | options[j][i];
        }
        merge_or.push_back(flag);
    }

    cout << "AND ";
    for (const auto &i : merge_and) cout << i;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "OR ";
    for (const auto &i : merge_or) cout << i;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
001
101
011

AND 001
OR 001
```

#### Further Metadata

If anyone is interested in the full implementation, once it's done and fully documented, I will upload it to my [GitHub account](https://github.com/UriyaHarpeness).

Thanks in advance for the helpers and commentators.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bitwise operations on vector<bool>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048749/bitwise-operations-on-vectorbool)

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far, otherwise it is very likely to be closed due to a lack of actual code.

Comment: @KenY-N, this does not answer my question, since it's not on the vectors separately, but on all of them, per index.

Comment: @KenY-N, adding code example in a minute.

Comment: @KenY-N updated with example, please review if you can,

Comment: Would `std::bitset<N>` better fit your needs? It has bitwise operators, the only requirement being that N is a compile-time constant. Or you can look at `boost::dynamic_bitset` which removes that restriction IIRC.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I do not know the size at compile time, and do you have an example which shows how it may help me with this?

Comment: There is a typo in your code. You print out `merged_and` instead of `merged_or`. It gives the correct result if edited.

Comment: correct, fixed.

Comment: Since we have a working example, then I think this is now a problem for [codereview.se]. From what I understand, `std::vector<bool>` is quite slow, so posting over there people might suggest how to use `boost::dynamic_bitset` efficiently.